# What is the difference between halfdelay() and cbreak() + timeout() when getting input?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I'm writing a typing game with ncurses in C++, and I noticed there are `cbreak()` and `halfdelay()` functions to switch modes for text input in ncurses.

I know `cbreak()` is used to disable line buffering when reading characters, and the difference between `cbreak()` and `halfdelay()` is `halfdelay()` take a parameter to blocking for X tenths.

And I was curious what if I use `cbreak()` with `timeout()`, does it works like `halfdelay()` ?

I made an experiment to see their difference:

Use `halfdelay()`:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    halfdelay(10); // blocking for 1s
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Use `cbreak()` and `timeout()`:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    timeout(1000); // blocking for 1s
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

I found both of behavior are waiting for a char and exit the programs immediately until exceed 1s, so I would like to ask if they have difference in ncurses?

Answer (score -2):

The halfdelay routine is used for half-delay mode. It's very similar to cbreak, but after blocking for tenths tenths of seconds, ERR (Error stream) is returned if nothing  has  been  typed.

You can find more informations about it here : [Link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/inopts.3ncurses.html)